# Way to suppress default 'edit' button in UINavigationController bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my storyboard, I have a `UITableViewController` (embedded in a `UINavigationController`) on which I have added a CANCEL button as a Left Bar Button Item.

At runtime, the CANCEL button doesn't appear, but an EDIT button does.

I haven't explicitly added the EDIT button and have kept the default implementation of the edit function in its disabled state thus:

```
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return false
}
```

I've looked into ways to hide the EDIT button and this line of code works:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)  
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
}
```

... in that it hides the EDIT button. But, it also hides the CANCEL and all other buttons on the left!

I have discovered code that explicitly shows the EDIT button, i.e.:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

But cannot find an equivalent for CANCEL.

So, is there a way to hide the EDIT button but show the CANCEL button?

--- UPDATE #1 ---

I have already connected the Cancel button to my class code via an IBOutlet per attached screenshot.
[image]

--- UPDATE #2 ---

I have now ensured that

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

and

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

are commented out. So, as far as I can tell, there is nothing about this TableViewController that enables editing of rows. Yet, the 'EDIT' button still appears and obfuscates my 'CANCEL' button.

Comment: A screen shot of your storyboard would be helpful.

Comment: cancel button and edit button both are left side ?
if yes then you should to do one thing why dont you do change title of that cancel button and check that button 's is selected bool value and according  that you do code and change title of it.

Comment: @Akash, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking me to do. I did try changing this to a 'custom' system, rather than a 'cancel'. I also changed the title of the button, but no change. And what do you mean by 'check that button is selected bool value'?

Comment: I don't think the "Edit" button is obfuscating the "Cancel' button.  I think it's replacing it.  Search your project for any reference to `leftBarButtonItem` or `leftBarButtonItems`.  Setting that property on a navigation item at runtime will override the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

`leftBarButtonItems` is a slightly different thing than `leftBarButtonItem`

It sounds like your cancel button has been added to the `leftBarButtonItems` of the navigationItem for your view controller, but you don't have a reference to it in your class.  Create an IBOutlet reference for it and you should be able to set it explicitly as the `leftBarButtonItem` in the same way as you are the edit button.

Comment: I already have an IBOutlet set for the Cancel button. See the update to my question with the Storyboard and code screenshot included.

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm time.

I had copied over a method from another class which had the edit button explicitly displayed the following line:

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`

Deleting this line removes the EDIT button at run time.